# How to add an Owner to Azure AD App Registration using MS Graph API

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to add an owner to an existing App Registration using MS Graph. I executed the below command.

```
az rest --method  PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/<Object-ID-of-SP>/owners/$ref --headers 'Content-type: application/json'
  {
    "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/<Object-ID-of-SP-Which-Should-Be-Added-As-The-Owner"
  }
```

But it gives the below error

```
The command failed with an unexpected error. Here is the traceback:
not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/azure-cli/2.45.0/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/cli/core/util.py", line 575, in shell_safe_json_parse
    return json.loads(json_or_dict_string, strict=strict)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.10_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py", line 359, in loads
    return cls(**kw).decode(s)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.10_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.10_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify `--url` parameter. According the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-owners?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), the method should be `POST`.

```
az rest --method post --url 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/<Object-ID-of-SP>/owners/$ref' --body '{"@odata.id":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/<Object-ID-of-SP-Which-Should-Be-Added-As-The-Owner"}'
```

Not sure, but the `az rest` [command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/use-cli-effectively?tabs=bash%2Cbash2#rest-api-commands-az-rest) automatically sets header `Content-Type: application/json`.